# Collision 100% avoidance implementation

Tags: collision-detection, ai

I'm an absolute beginner with game development and all I know about collision avoidance/resolution, I learnt it *on* or *through* this site in the past week... so don't hesitate to correct me if what I'm asking here is based on wrong assumptions / misunderstanding. I tried of my best to be clear, but that said, the subject is still novel to me.

### Vehicles

In my game, I have vehicles that move autonomously. They are placed in a 3D space, and their motion is governed by a number of variables which are different for each vehicles. The one of interest here are primarily:

- Only *forward* motion.
- A *speed* that can vary between min & max, but whose min is **not** (even close to) zero.
- A *steering radius* that is dependent from the speed (the higher speed, the larger radius)
- Two *maximum accelerations* (for decreasing and increasing speed)

### Goal

My goal is to implement some sort of AI that will a **100% accurate collision avoidance** (i.e. I will be sure that the vehicles will **never ever** collide).

### Design

- Although **I would prefer more the idea of having the AI "onboard"** (i.e. each vehicle having it's own "collision avoidance AI", eventually querying and/or sending messages to other vehicles) it is also possible for me to implement the CA AI at a central level (dispatching commands to the vehicles).
- In most of the cases, the vehicle will simply have to steer clear of each other in any direction, but under certain circumstances, they will have to avoid collision **and going towards the same target**

### What I found so far and where I got stuck

Within the many many links I found in other questions on this very site, I found of particular use these ones:

1. [Collision between pool balls](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3015/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php)
2. [Unalligned collision avoidance](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/Unaligned.html)
3. [Queuing](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/Doorway.html)

While these three links "opened my eyes" in many ways, it is not immediately clear to me how to use that information in my case. In particular article #2 only "tries" to prevent collision (but collisions do happens time to time). While article #3 needs to stop vehicles sometimes to prevent collisions.

What I also noticed, is that the collision avoidance algorithms linked above use a **"instant projection" of linear speed** to check if something is on the way of the vehicle. I was wondering if this is enough in my case or if I had to project my position in a more realistic way (e.g.: If I am 60° into a steering 90° to the right, I should calculate my position for the rest of the 30° of the curve, and then assuming linear motion).

Finally, I am particularly **afraid of deadlocks**. In other words: although the density of vehicles in the world will be fairly low, I am worried that given a certain numbers of vehicles converging towards the same point, once they will realise they are on a collision course, any evasive manoeuvres will be impossible as it would bring the vehicle on a collision path with some other ones.

### Question

**How can I reach my "goal"?** An in depth-explanation is of course very much appreciated, but links to external resources would also be of great help (I'm sure I'm not the first with this problem, but probably I used the wrong keywords to search the web?)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Have every vehicle stop. 100% avoidance achieved.

Comment: @Martin - As clearly stated in the question, this is not a possibility.

Comment: It's enough if they stop relative to each other. That is, all of them move in the exactly same direction, at exactly same speed. The bigger problem is that it's (provably) IMPOSSIBLE to achieve any algorithm which does it at 100% rate for every possible configuration. For example, consider two vehicles with very large turning radii at the minimum distance not equal to zero from each other, flying at each other with max speed.

Comment: What kind of world are these vihicles moving in? If it's in a 'real world' situation, just make them abide by the highway code.

Comment: @Martin - Same speed is not a possibility (as specified in the "vehicles" bit: each vehicle has its own speed ranges).

Comment: @mac: Speed ranges can overlap. :)

Comment: @3nixios - Can you articulate a bit more on your proposal? The vehicles are airborne with the airspace quadrant approximated to a cuboid.

Comment: @mac From what is in your question I couldn't discern that the vehicles were airborne. Your AI should probably implement [Air Traffic Avoidance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_collision_avoidance_system), the work has already been done for you, why not use it?

Comment: @mac - One thing to keep in mind as you develop this algorithm is that It's A Game. If you're spending too much time trying to solve this problem, maybe you're trying to solve the wrong problem. You can cheat - move vehicles or violate their handling rules if you detect a difficult situation, especially if the player can't see it. Make sure whatever vehicle handling rules you come up with don't end up looking boring, it's more important to be entertaining than to be right.

Comment: @3nixios - I'm well aware of TCAS (hank you anyhow for the link), but AFAIK its design is such that it only "steer clear" **both** vehicles. It does not actually reroute the vehicle to an alternative path to reach the same point nor it gives way to either of the vehicles. This means that two vehicles approaching the same target would both miss it (as they would be both steered clear of it). Under certain conditions this could even generate a looping equilibrium...

Comment: @mac Well I would probably use a global controller with A*. I know you wanted to stay away from this solution, but it makes more sense as it has a global view of the vehicles and it can pre-calculate paths. You may also want to put a priority on vehicles (the one closest to the target gets a higher priority, so it's path remains unchanged and others re-route around it).

Comment: @Flip A flight simulator is still considered a game, yet if you 'cheated', it would break the game for any player that realized this.

Comment: @3nixios: True, but since the problem is ultimately unsolvable (you can only guarantee 0 collisions if they're all moving in the same direction at the same speed), you have to pick which is worse: occasional cheating or mid-air collisions.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas With a global manager solution I believe the problem is very solvable. The problem could be the prediction distance, if it is too far it may not be a real time solution.

Comment: Even if you did have initially-moving vehicles with 100% collision avoidance, arbitrary starting conditions could still cause [gridlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gridlock).

Comment: Since the vehicles are apparently airborne, why not use the "Unalligned collision avoidance" steering behavior, but extend it so that vehicles can fly over/beneath another vehicle when a collision is imminent? Eg. just use that third dimension if one of the rare collision will occur.

Comment: @bummzack - Using the third dimension is already part of the behaviour of the vehicles. Still, there are certain limitations, as they can't fly above or below a certain altitude. Also, they "regular" altitude vary, so using different levels as different priorities to escape collision is not an option.

Comment: @Darien - gridlocks/deadlocks are indeed part of my concern. I am wondering if the pattern proposed by eBusiness would allow to escape this situation though. Differently than cars at a blocked crossing, circling flying vehicles still change their position over time, so it might be that is still possible to find a "window" through neighbouring circling vehicles...

Comment: @mac I see. Maybe you should add these additional constraints to your question because they seem quite relevant. On a side note: Are you simulating some sort of "Fifth Element Traffic" scenario? :)

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked into **flocking algorithms**? When I look at your description that's what comes to mind for me. There's lots of articles around for this, here's [one I like](http://rocketmandevelopment.com/2010/10/08/steering-behaviors-flocking/). Likely you won't be using all the aspects of flocking, like cohesion. Most of the aspects would be useful for what you're trying to do, like alignment and separation, both of which would help in avoiding collisions. You'd end up with something a bit different than flocking, but it should help you get started.

Good luck!

Comment: The relevent search-term here is [Boids](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/).  However, I don't think this is what OP was looking for - it sounds more like he wants cars going every-which way.

Comment: Flocking is still about the AI avoiding collision with eachother.

Comment: OP asks for reliable collision avoidance. Flocking poses no guarantees, as the force based model does not incorporate hard constraints. Although flocking is surely a good entry point to get into the topic, the answer is thus missplaced. I suggest the OP to look for "velocity obstacles" instead.

Comment: @TobiasGurdan If you have an answer that's more appropriate (and I agree that you do), you should create an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach: Every vehicle has a short projected path where the vehicle in the end slows down and enters a loop, these paths may not overlap. Whenever a vehicle comes to the point where it is set to slow down you try to generate a new path that does not overlap any of the existing. If that is not found to be possible the vehicle continues on it's given path and retries making a new path periodically.

The method could be improved to allow tighter traffic by letting paths leading to loops overlap each other and loops where it can be determined that this will not cause a collision.

Answer (score 0):

Have a method in each vehicle where it performs a radial search around itself, if there are any other vehicles inside this radius, move away in a fashion suitable to your liking: 1) Move in the opposite vector, 2) slow down, 3) speed up, etc.

You can even do combinations: If the other vehicle's vector is not straight ahead or directly behind: move away; else if it is straight ahead: slow down; else: speed up.

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to implement some sort of AI that will a 100% accurate collision avoidance (i.e. I will be sure that the vehicles will never ever collide).

If this were possible, it would have been put into all the world's aircraft by now.

I suggest relaxing the 'autonomous' aspect and having a function that resolves predicted collisions between 2 (or more) vehicles. It can be as naive as picking random new directions to travel in and seeing if that resolves the problem, but the important thing is that the function only returns when it's reached an agreement that suits both vehicles.

I also suggest that any vehicle that is predicted to collide in the near future reduces its speed while maintaining the same look-ahead distance - this will give your vehicles more opportunity to avoid collisions, just as in real life.

Comment: Since he's designing the rules of the universe, it's absolutely possible.  The real world is obviously more complicated, but I'm sure real-world aircraft do use a ton of collision-avoidance techniques...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that *crowd simulation* might be the topic most relevant to what you're trying to achieve. The GAMMA group at UNC has a large body of work on the subject that might be worth looking through. Their description:

> Crowd and multi-agent simulation is the process of simulating large
>   numbers of people, creatures, or other characters, each interacting in
>   one environment. These actors are expected to move to their goals,
>   interact with their environment, and respond to each other. Crowd
>   simulations have many uses, including improving architectural
>   planning, enhancing training environments and virtual realties, and
>   **driving artificially-intelligent (AI) characters in games** and movies.
>   Our group has worked on many problems in crowd simulation, **including
>   fast, guaranteed, collision avoidance, real-time path and motion
>   planning,** crowd flows, and directed behaviors.

http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/research/crowds/

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a 100% avoidance method, but if you vehicles possess full world informations, you could encase each vehicle into a box whose length depend on its speed, and perform collision check on those boxes. If there is indeed a collision, steer away, with a strength depending on the imminence of impact (or area of the collision between the two boxes), and slow dow (but keep your box the same length during the avoidance operation).

Obviously this won't work if the vehicles does not posses full informations, but in this case nothing will garanty a 100% avoidance (except, as already said, parallel movement)

some methods described [here](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/) would probably be useful, notably this one :[Unaligned Collision Avoidance steering behavior](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/Unaligned.html)

regards

Comment: Did you read the original question? That link you recommended is already in the question...